# Why is my code not printing (complete beginner)

Tags: python, printing

I have a question about the below code, I just started coding and I'm doing the second python challenge on Hackerrank. I want to test if my code works by checking if it 6 is weird but my code isn't printing.

```
N=8
if N % 2 ==1 and N >= 6 and N <20:
    print("Weird")
    else:
        print ("Not weird")
```

So if N is a commute of 2 and between 6 and 20 it should print Weird all else should print not weird, but its not printing. Could you tell me whats wrong with my code?

Comment: Your indentation is not correct. The `else:` should start at the same column as the `if`, and the two `print` statements should line up as well. Indentation is important in Python.

Comment: If you actually ran this code, you would get an error message. You should mention that in your question.

Comment: Note that `N % 2 == 1` Will return true for odd integers greater than or equal to 3. Make sure this is what you intend.

Comment: @Khelwood, yes i should indeed but I just saw that my kernel in jupiternotebook was not running properly. I restarted anaconda navigator and it works now, and yes i saw an error haha. But i've tried your answer BurhanKhalid and now it prints! thanks for your help. The answer is still wrong but i'll try to fix my code. Chris thanks i'm going to look in to this.

Comment: @Chris `N%2==1` is true for _any_ odd number, regardless of whether it is greater than 3.

Comment: @khelwood You’re right! My mistake - I quickly assumed wrongly that 1 would be the exception but of course that’s not the case!

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? If you try to run the code as you posted it, you should get an error about the indentation.

Comment: @Barmar my kernel in jupiternotebook wasn't working, but yes it gave an error when i restarted it.

Answer (score 3):

The else line must be indented at the same level as the if statement. Indentation is key in python. Try this:

```
N=8
if N % 2 ==1 and N >= 6 and N <20:
    print("Weird")
else:
    print ("Not weird")
```

Answer (score 2):

Your indent for `else` is incorrect. Also, your condition N>=6 is redundant isn't it? When N%2 for 6 will lead to 0, it will automatically print the else condition. You can, and should use N>6 or N>=7.

```
N=8
if N % 2 ==1 and N >= 6 and N <20:
    print("Weird")
else:
    print ("Not weird")
```

Comment: Why is there a need to try? It's pretty straight forward. The code will work as it is. Just pointing out a redundant condition.

Comment: Ahh you meant the my suggestion for shortening it. Thanks for pointing that out!